# Best approach to pass a string to a legacy function expecting char array as parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, stdstring

Suppose that we have a c-style legacy function that is filling a char array passed as parameter with a filename, and we cannot refactor it. On the other side, the calling functions are now using std::string.

What are the standard/best approaches to pass the string of the calling function to the legacy function?

What I usually see is to create a temporary char array in the calling function, that is used as argument when calling the legacy function, and then the std::string is set with the char array (method 1 in the source code below).

I am wondering if I can safely avoid to create the temporary char array and instead use the string directly. I tried a few methods (method 2 to 6 below) and the method 4 seems fine to me, but I am not sure if I am missing something in term of safety/reliability. Are there better solutions?

Also, I am also not sure to understand why method 4 is working when setting the size to `FILENAME_SIZE` while method 5 does not work and I have to use `FILENAME_SIZE - 1` instead (method 6).

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

// Suppose that filenames are hardcoded to 20 characters
const std::size_t FILENAME_SIZE = 21;

// Suppose that we have a legacy function to get a filename
// and suppose that the legacy function handles correctly the filename max size
// based on FILENAME_SIZE
void getFilename(char* anArray)
{
    // write the filename into anArray
    // for this test, i use strncp
    strncpy(anArray, "123456789", FILENAME_SIZE - 1);
}

int main()
{
    // Method 1 -> OK
    std::string aString1;
    char anArray1[FILENAME_SIZE] = {};

    getFilename(anArray1);
    aString1 = anArray1;

    std::cout << "Method 1" << std::endl;
    std::cout << anArray1 << "/" << std::endl;
    std::cout << aString1 << "/" << std::endl;

    // Method 2 -> KO
    std::string aString2;

    getFilename(&aString2[0]);

    std::cout << "Method 2" << std::endl;
    std::cout << aString2 << "/" << std::endl;

    // Method 3 -> KO
    std::string aString3;
    aString3.reserve(FILENAME_SIZE);

    getFilename(&aString3[0]);

    std::cout << "Method 3" << std::endl;
    std::cout << aString3 << "/" << std::endl;

    // Method 4 -> OK
    std::string aString4;
    aString4.resize(FILENAME_SIZE);

    getFilename(&aString4[0]);

    std::cout << "Method 4" << std::endl;
    std::cout << aString4 << "/" << std::endl;

    // Method 5 -> KO
    std::string aString5 = std::string(FILENAME_SIZE, '0');

    getFilename(&aString5[0]);

    std::cout << "Method 5" << std::endl;
    std::cout << aString5 << "/" << std::endl;

    // Method 6 -> OK
    std::string aString6 = std::string(FILENAME_SIZE-1, '0');

    getFilename(&aString6[0]);

    std::cout << "Method 6" << std::endl;
    std::cout << aString6 << "/" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Method 1
123456789/
123456789/
Method 2
/
Method 3
/
Method 4
123456789/
Method 5
1234567890/
Method 6
123456789/
```

Comment: If you look at the `length()` of each string after the copy, you'll see only method 1 has the proper length.

Comment: I see now. I assume that this is the reason why method 1 is usually used.